# Server freezes completely in unknown condition

Tags: ubuntu

I've recently assembled a server for virtualization. The problem is undetected in installation. When I deployed applications (based on openstack under ubuntu 12.04), the server freezes in random time (usually 10 to 40 hours). It could survive extreme stress test which means there is no temperature problem. It is interesting that when the kernel has used up almost all of the memory for buffer (I tried by using dd), the system is nearly frozen and cannot receive any incoming network connection, but connected still remains. According to the manual applications should always be able to allocate memory from buffer if there is no other free memory.

Also, I tried to dig something from syslog but there is to much from kernel

**UPDATE**

After some waiting I got some useful information. The server did not crashed after kernel upgrade but leave something.

```
Jan 24 19:38:25 shisoft-vmhost kernel: [ 5083.584670] sbridge: HANDLING MCE MEMORY ERROR
Jan 24 19:38:25 shisoft-vmhost kernel: [ 5083.751554] EDAC MC0: 2 CE memory read error on CPU_SrcID#0_Channel#1_DIMM#0 (channel:1 slot:0 page:0xc8b77d offset:0x40 grain:32 syndrome:0x0 -  OVERFLOW area:DRAM err_code:0001:0091 socket:0 channel_mask:1 rank:1)
```

Looks like memory issue, any ideas?

Comment: You need to learn to extract relevant information from your logs. Without it we can't help you.

Comment: 1. Is your sever hardware on [Ubuntu's HCL](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/server/)? 2. Stress tests guarantee nothing; what does your monitoring software report for temperatures or other environmental conditions? 3. The kernel using memory for cache/buffer is completely normal and at best a red herring, it's *not a problem* (and we regularly argue with people about that). 4. What exactly do you mean by "freezes"? Sounds like you mean that networking becomes unresponsive...

Comment: @ChrisS Temperature report is normal, freezes means by server cannot control by network and keyboard.I cannot find anything useful from the blog, I am now running memory test.

Comment: @ChrisS I got something, is it useful to find where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RAM in the server is bad: channel:1 slot:0, which is probably the first stick in the second channel.

Comment: Thank you, but it appears that this issue only occurred once after this reboot. I am not very sure this is the real problem. Is there any possible an false alert?

Comment: Typical Non-ECC RAM has a FIT of about 1e-7/bit or better. That's 0.0000001 errors per 1,000,000,000 bit-hours of operation. It's certainly possible. Perhaps you should buy a lottery ticket. If it's ECC RAM, which it should be if this is a server, the numbers go up astronomically.

Comment: I got it. It's ECC memory and it's sure a problem. Is there possible other component could cause this problem? Like motherboard or processor?

Comment: Unfortunately it could be either of those as well. If your board has some sort of system management (IPMI, iLO, ILOM, DRAC, etc) it may have logged more details of the error. I saw a similar error in an HP server once, iLO logged a memory channel error (indicating that the RAM itself wasn't bad), and rearranging the RAM confirmed the problem was with the Mobo (at that time the memory controller was in the northbridge, not in the CPU, so the CPU wasn't a possible culprit then).

Comment: My board has IPMI but I don't see any logs for what kind of issue.